# Safe insert/removal of XBee from circuit

Tags: power, xbee, esd

Is it safe to remove an XBee or similar radio module while the host is still powered up?

I am trying to build a programming jig using an ARM11. The peripheral board is connected with TTL level UART and SPI.

What precautions should I take when swapping boards? Is a ZIF socket neccesary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. You need to

1. Make sure the ground mates first (and breaks last)
2. Then power
3. Then the signals.
   and
4. Limit current with a soft-start circuit.

ZIF is strictly a mechanical issue; it does nothing about the electrical problems.